# No changes occur once everything is saved and refreshed

Tags: html, css

I am entirely new to coding, just done about 8 tutorial videos to see if I have any aptitude for this to then go back to school for my 5th attempt at a career path. So as I was coding we get to the "Code images section" and I type the provided code below but the only value that is affected is the color so I am not sure what is interfering with it.

I have tried recreating the code, cutting parts that might interfere with it but no luck.

```css
   header .logo a {
        background: red;
        width: 300px;
        text-indent: -99999999999px;
    }
```

```html
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href= "1.html">1</a></li>
                <li><a href= "2.html">2</a></li>
                <li class="logo"><a href= "index.html">Artisan</a></li>
                <li><a href= "3.html">3</a></li>
                <li><a href= "4.html">4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

I expect the text to be removed by the indent and the bounding box to be extended but only the color seems to change.

Comment: It seems fine in this example. Is the CSS in your head section of the file or an external CSS file? If it's external be sure to do a hard refresh (CTRL+F5 or ⌘ + R)

Comment: Maybe cache (as tshumkus said) or bad selector in CSS. You can't put here relevant CSS, so just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: Give your `<a>` a block layout…

```
header .logo a {
  background: red;
  width: 300px;
  text-indent: -99999999999px;
  display: inline-block; // or `display: block`
}
```

The `<a>` inherits an `inline` layout by default. Elements with the `inline` layout ignore certain CSS rules — namely height & width, which effectively means that any rule that relies on positioning based on finite coordinates (your `text-indent`, for instance) won't work. You can read more on `inline` versus `block` layout models in [this article on `display` on css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/).

```css
header .logo a {
  background: red;
  width: 300px;
  text-indent: -99999999999px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="1.html">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="2.html">2</a></li>
      <li class="logo"><a href="index.html">Artisan</a></li>
      <li><a href="3.html">3</a></li>
      <li><a href="4.html">4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: OK, understood. Thanks a lot and I'll check out those pages.

Comment: If that answer was helpful to you — and you think others might benefit from finding it in the future — consider accepting it as the "answer"? [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)